# Finding an upper bound for square root of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am dealing with a determinant. $F=\frac{n^2}{n^2-1} (I-\frac{2}{n+1}dd^T)$ where $d$ is a vector(column) of length $1$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and $I$ is identity matrix. Do you know any way to prove $\sqrt{\det F}\le e^{\frac{-1}{2(n+1)}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You know the eigenvalues of $dd^T$ explicitly
2. Hence you know the eigenvalues of $F$
3. Their product gives you $\det F$
4. Some algebra required to obtain the required estimation, but I suspect nothing too complicated

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now I understand.